# Get Confidence Interval For One Point On Regression Line In R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, confidence-interval

How do I get the CI for one point on the regression line? I'm quite sure I should use confint() for that, but if I try this

```
confint(model,param=value)
```

it just gives me the same number as if I just type in

```
confint(model)
```

if I try without a value, it does not give me any values at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you read `?confint` carefully I suspect you'll discover that it is not what you want. You probably simply want to use `predict.lm`.

Comment: Also, you might want to read a bit about [confidence vs prediction](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16493/5055) intervals, just to make sure you're getting what you want.

Answer (score 21):

You want `predict()` instead of `confint()`. Also, as Joran noted, you'll need to be clear about whether you want the confidence interval or prediction interval for a given x. (A confidence interval expresses uncertainty about the *expected* value of y-values at a given x. A prediction interval expresses uncertainty surrounding the predicted y-value of a single sampled point with that value of x.)

Here's a simple example of how to do this in R:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10 + rnorm(10))

f <- lm(y~x, data=df)

predict(f, newdata=data.frame(x=c(0, 5.5, 10)), interval="confidence")
#         fit       lwr       upr
# 1 0.5500246 -1.649235  2.749284
# 2 5.7292889  4.711230  6.747348
# 3 9.9668688  8.074662 11.859075

predict(f, newdata=data.frame(x=c(0, 5.5, 10)), interval="prediction")
#         fit       lwr       upr
# 1 0.5500246 -3.348845  4.448895
# 2 5.7292889  2.352769  9.105809
# 3 9.9668688  6.232583 13.701155
```

Comment: Well written, as usual. The up votes on my comment had finally prompted me to get off my butt and write an actual answer, but you saved me the trouble!

Comment: @joran -- Thanks. `predict`'s `newdata` argument and the distinction between confidence and prediction intervals are both tricky enough that I too thought it worth the effort to explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: Nice answer. I would have hoped that predicting outside the domain of information would generate a warning.

Comment: @42 predictions are by definition outside the domain of information.

Comment: @DzamoNorton Pretty sure he meant "predictions for values of x beyond the range of x's actually observed. So (exaggerating just for purposes of illustration) if you've fitted a model relating power of car engines (the dependent or "y" variable) to their volume (the independent or "x" variable), you probably shouldn't try using it to predict the power of an engine with a volume of 10 cubic meters. I think he was really using the term "domain" in [a more precise, technical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function).

Comment: @DzamoNorton Perhaps you would be happier with `range` (as the R function meaning of difference of min and max) of domain? ... with domain being the "x"-values and "range" (in the alternate functional terminology) being the "y"-values.

Comment: @42: okay "domain" in the sense of maths :).  I still think such a warning would generally be odd: "warning, weather/share price/global avg temperature forecast includes tomorrow which is outside the domain of information".

Comment: I prefer to label such "predictions" by the term "forecasts". Multiple regression is more commonly used to make predictions within the confines of hyperboxes measured by the ranges of values along the covariate dimensions.