# R: is there a way to get the confidence/prediction interval around a predicted value

Tags: r, confidence-interval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Confidence Interval For One Point On Regression Line In R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732424/get-confidence-interval-for-one-point-on-regression-line-in-r)

I have created a linear model in R, using a data frame, to predict the next outcome of my variable given updated inputs for my regressors. ( I had to manually compute the predicted value using calc, as I dont understand how to plug values into linear model variables.)

My question is how do I find out the confidence interval at the 95% level for the predicted value I just found? Is there a way to do this in R, or do I have to manually compute the C.I. for this predicted value using stats formulas?

When I run predict(LM,data=x,interval="confidence") I just get intervals for every single piece of data in the set.

(knowing this, I tried to manually add in the predicted dependent and my updated regressors into my data frame, but failed as I could not find the proper code to add data to specific columns in a dataframe)

Confused.

Comment: See this related SO question for an example of how to get CI's around a predicted value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732424/get-confidence-interval-for-one-point-on-regression-line-in-r/12732693#12732693

Comment: I voted to close as this covers the same ground as the question Josh discusses.  If you need further direction on joining the two outputs please provide specific output hat you've tried.  `cbind` will likely be useful in accomplishing this task.